# Is there an YOLO fault for python script?

Tags: yolo

I clone https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet ,then build in windows10!
 Run "./darknet detect cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights data/dog.jpg" is no problem,but when run "python python/darknet.py" report error"Segmentation fault".
What can i do next?

Comment: Asking the forums for the project in question would be a better place to get answers on how to run it.

Comment: you could try running it in a VMWare/VirtualBox linux VM and see if it still crashes there? Youtube-dl, another program written in python, is prone to segfaulting on my win10 machine too, but never segfaults in my Xubuntu VM on the same machine =/

Comment: Try with python3 command. Do you get a traceback of the error?